# Is there a possibility when calling .ToUpper() that the new string requires more memory?

Tags: c#, string

I want to use the the following function in the MemoryExtensions namespace

```
public static int ToUpper(this ReadOnlySpan<char> source, Span<char> destination, CultureInfo? culture)
```

My question now is: am I always safe when destination Span has the length of the source span? e.g.

```
destination = stackalloc char[source.Length];
```

If no, can someone provide an example which string converts to a larger string when calling ToUpper on in (including which culture)?

Comment: I _want_ to say yes, but I know some character sets/cultures do **weird** things when certain letters are capitalized. I'd expect you'd be fine 99.99%+ of the time, but that extra 0.01% could be killer. Or maybe you are perfectly fine... I'm not an expert here, and I'm interested to see if anyone could prove otherwise.

Comment: The one example that I could think of, which might do this, was German ""viel spaß", possibly turning the `ß` character into `SS`, but it turns out that it is left alone by `string.ToUpper(new CultureInfo("de-DE"))`.

Comment: All characters can range from 1-4 bytes, with mostly international chars taking up the 4 bytes. You should look into [.GetByteCount()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getbytecount?view=net-7.0). This site has a [table](https://design215.com/toolbox/utf8-4byte-characters.php) of the different UTF-8 1-4 byte characters.  That being said, Dotnet is [UTF-16 encoding by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-encoding). which is 2-4 bytes per character. So I am guessing that it spacing would be `source.Length * 4` at most

Comment: I bring all this up to say: `stackalloc` will reserve a block of memory of that *length* but I don't see its documentation making any notes about *size in bytes*. The compiler probably would like to handle the byte size concerns for strings on its own, because it likes to do its own optimizations and all that. So I think you are fine, but I don't truly know. You will need to lean on CultureInfo for the best results

Comment: ß could also turn into ẞ, the former having 2 utf-8 bytes and the latter having 3 utf-8 bytes, though as @500-InternalServerError pointed out german culture appears to just ignore ß

Comment: @Narish `stackalloc` will allocate that many `<sizeInBytesOfYourType>` which in this case is `2 * source.Length`

Comment: Don't know C#, but another possible edge case to investigate is that in Turkish the uppercase of the letter `i` (U+0069) is *not* `I` (U+0049) but instead `İ` (U+0130). In UTF8 the lower-case fits in 1-byte, but the upper-case needs 2-bytes.

Comment: "by default" is underselling it. .net (like Java and windows NT) *always* uses UTF-16 as it's internal working format. UTF-8 has no relevance to this question.

Comment: So a ToUpper would only change the length (in UTF-16 code units, which are what matter) if it either changed the number of code points, or if the mapping involved code points beyond the basic multilingual plane.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[`MemoryExtensions.ToUpper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memoryextensions.toupper?view=net-7.0#returns) returns `-1` if the destination is too small.

The [source code for `ToUpper`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/a5b75b8179d7db4ff720e19233d2b99fd15b94f0/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/MemoryExtensions.Globalization.cs#L249) has this gem:

```cs
// Assuming that changing case does not affect length
if (destination.Length < source.Length)
    return -1;
```

There is no other point where `-1` is returned, the function finishes with `return source.Length;`

So they've assumed it can't happen. Whether they're right is another question: if you find a counter-example I suggest you file a bug report on GitHub.

The [docs for `TextInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.textinfo.toupper?view=net-7.0#system-globalization-textinfo-toupper(system-string)) (used later on in the code) say:

> The returned string might differ in length from the input string. For more information on casing, refer to the Unicode Technical Report #21 "Case Mappings," published by the Unicode Consortium (https://www.unicode.org/). **The current implementation preserves the length of the string.** However, this behavior is not guaranteed and could change in future implementations.

---

To clarify further, we are talking about code points in UTF-16. We have not considered UTF-8 or UTF-32, as `char` is strictly UTF-16.

Unicode defines Case Mapping as follows:

> - **Simple (Single-Character) Case Mapping**
>
>   The general case mapping in ICU is non-language based and a 1 to 1 generic character map.
>
>   A character is considered to have a lowercase, uppercase, or title case equivalent if there is a respective “simple” case mapping specified for the character in the Unicode Character Database (UnicodeData.txt). If a character has no mapping equivalent, the result is the character itself.
>
>   The APIs provided for the general case mapping, located in uchar.h file, handles only single characters of type UChar32 and returns only single characters. To convert a string to a non-language based specific case, use the APIs in either the unistr.h or ustring.h files with a NULL argument locale.
> - **Full (Language-Specific) Case Mapping**
>
>   There are different case mappings for different locales. For instance, unlike English, the character Latin small letter ‘i’ in Turkish has an equivalent Latin capital letter ‘I’ with dot above ( \u0130 ‘İ’).
>
>   Similar to the simple case mapping API, a character is considered to have a lowercase, uppercase or title case equivalent if there is a respective mapping specified for the character in the Unicode Character database (UnicodeData.txt). In the case where a character has no mapping equivalent, the result is the character itself.
>
>   To convert a string to a language based specific case, use the APIs in ustring.h and unistr.h with an intended argument locale.
>
>   ICU implements full Unicode string case mappings.
>
>   In general:
>
>   - **case mapping can change the number of code points and/or code units of a string,**
>   - is language-sensitive (results may differ depending on language), and
>   - is context-sensitive (a character in the input string may map differently depending on surrounding characters).

### TL;DR;

In theory, the number of code points could change (this is separate from the number of bytes). But .NET does not currently implement this. That could change without notice, but that's unlikely until there is a way to calculate the number of code points, due to interdependencies on `Span`.

Comment: What [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.textinfo.toupper?view=net-7.0#system-globalization-textinfo-toupper(system-string)) says about it: *The returned string might differ in length from the input string. For more information on casing, refer to the Unicode Technical Report #21 "Case Mappings," published by the Unicode Consortium (https://www.unicode.org). The current implementation preserves the length of the string. However, this behavior is not guaranteed and could change in future implementations.*

Comment: True but I think at that point there would have to be a new API surface which would return the required length, as there are a number of places that this assumption is made. There isn't even such a function buried privately in `TextInfo` and associated classes.

Comment: I think everybody is thinking in bytes.  In bytes, it is almost certainly true that the strings would be different lengths in some circumstances, but the code sample given specifies *char* as the data type.  A char is always a char.  Depending on the character set in *use* and the version and flavor of language employed, that might translate to 1, 2, 3 or even more *bytes*, but for the purposes of this discussion, that's irrelevant.  It's still one char.  In C#, it will be one char, regardless of how many bytes it occupies.

Comment: @Yrth I don't think that is strictly true. According to the Unicode Case Mappings "In general: * case mapping can change the number of code points and/or code units of a string, * is language-sensitive (results may differ depending on language), and * is context-sensitive (a character in the input string may map differently depending on surrounding characters)."

Comment: So the fact that .NET does it this way doesn't necessarily mean it's right, or that it won't change in the future. As far as bytes is concerned, I haven't discussed that at all, the discussion is only if a single `char` could map to multiple `char` codepoints, or vv, and that could be the case according to the Unicode.

Comment: @Charlieface You've got me there.  I forgot that, from a computer's point of view, 'd' and 'D' are essentially equivalent to 'r' and 'Z' - totally different elements.  We ourselves assign equivalence to them.